# Spring Batch read from one table and insert into another

Tags: spring-batch

Im using Spring boot and Spring batch to read and insert into two different tables.

jdbc cursor reads record by record in below code snippet, don't know how to persists this into insert statement record by record.

```
     @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Studdetail> jdbcitemReader()  {

        JdbcCursorItemReader<Studdetail> jdbcItemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        
        jdbcItemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        
        jdbcItemReader.setSql("SELECT * FROM Schema1.Table1");
        
        jdbcItemReader.setRowMapper(new StuddetailRowMapper());
        
        int counter = 0;
        
        ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
        
        jdbcItemReader.open(executionContext);
        
        Object Studdetail = new Studetail();
        
        while(Studdetail != null){
            
        try {
        
        Studdetail = jdbcItemReader.read();

                   jdbcitemWriter() ;
        
        } catch (UnexpectedInputException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
            counter++;
           }
    
        jdbcItemReader.close();
        
        return jdbcItemReader;
    }
    
 
 private static final String QUERY_INSERT_STUDENT = "INSERT " + "INTO Schema2.Table2(Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6) " + "VALUES(:ID1,:ID2,:ID3,:ID4,:ID5,:ID6)";
    
    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Studdetail> jdbcitemWriter()  {
        
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Studdetail> jdbcItemWriter= new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        
        jdbcItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
        
        jdbcItemWriter.setSql(QUERY_INSERT_STUDENT);
        
        ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Studdetail> paramProvider = new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>();
        
        jdbcItemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(paramProvider);

        return jdbcItemWriter;
        
    }
```

Records are populated in Studdetail in jdbcitemReader()  but unable to insert.
No errors or exceptions, i know missing something while insert. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You're reading and writing at the same time, maybe you should split the task ItemReader and ItemWriter.

```
@Bean
public Job sampleJob() {
    return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("sampleJob")
                .start(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
}

@Bean
public Step step1() {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<String, String>chunk(2)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .writer(databaseItemWriter())
                .build();
}

@Bean
public JdbcCursorItemReader<Studdetail> itemReader() {
    return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Studdetail>()
            .dataSource(this.dataSource)
            .name("studdetail")
            .sql("SELECT * FROM Schema1.Table1")
            .rowMapper(new StuddetailRowMapper())
            .build();

}
private static final String QUERY_INSERT_STUDENT = "INSERT " + "INTO Schema2.Table2(Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6) " + "VALUES(:ID1,:ID2,:ID3,:ID4,:ID5,:ID6)";

@Bean
public ItemWriter<Studdetail> databaseItemWriter() {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Studdetail> databaseItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    databaseItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
    databaseItemWriter.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);

    databaseItemWriter.setSql(QUERY_INSERT_STUDENT);

    return databaseItemWriter;
}
```

Comment: thank you..it worked after splitting reader and writer